# Java - Create a multiplication table using strings

Tags: java, string, multiplication

So I recently got an this assignment in class and need help, I've checked out other questions but couldn't find one that was similar to what my teacher was asking for. She is pretty strict and want's things exactly how they're asked for.

"Create a class called MultiplicationTable and MultiplicationTableTester. A multiplication table has a max.

The Multiplication table should have method called String createMultiplcationTable() that creates a multiplication table.

Use “\n” to obtain a new line, the program should use the string “\t” to tab to the next tab position, so that the information is displayed neatly 
in the columns. The MultiplicationTableTester class should prompt the user for the max (don’t allow the user to enter negative number, 
if they do continue prompting them for a valid value until one is entered)."

This is my horrible attempt at doing this

```
/* MultiplicationTable.java*/

public class MultiplacationTable {
private int maxNum;
private int i = 1;

public MultiplacationTable(int n) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    maxNum = in.nextInt();
    n = maxNum;
}

public String createMultiplacationTable() {
        String row = "";
        String col = "";
        String tmpRow= "";
        String tmpCol = "";
        String table = "";

    while (i < maxNum) {
        tmpRow = "" + i;
        i++;
        row += tmpRow + "\t";

        tmpCol = "" + i;
        i++;
        col += tmpCol + "/n";
            for (int j = 1;  j < maxNum; j++) {
                System.out.print(" " + i * j);
    }
            table = row + col;
    }
    return table;
 }
}
```

Didn't know what to do with the tester besides print out the method

```
/*MultiplicationTableTester*/

public class MultiplacationTableTester {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Please input a number: ");

     MultiplacationTable mT = new MultiplacationTable(0);
     System.out.print(mT.createMultiplacationTable());
  }
}
```

My output using 5 as input is

```
Please input a number: 5
3 6 9 12 5 10 15 201    3   2/n4/n
```

So obviously really wrong. I have a feeling what I'm doing wrong has to do with the "/n" and "\t". Any help?

Comment: Your assignment said to use `\n` but you are using `/n`. `\n` means "newline", `/n` means literally  "a string containing character `/` followed by `n`".

Comment: Welcome @Conas. This is an excellent site to gain information but it is not a homework site. Don't expect people to do your homework for you.  Rather ask a specific question

Comment: Parameter `int n` to the constructor of MultiplacationTable is useless. You can get rid of it.

Comment: @TungstenX He actually asked a specific question and made progress about it. This is a valid and good question.

Comment: @EmreAcar Isn't this filling up SO with homework specific questions that will only help the person asking? Thus not adding value to the overall knowledge base?

Comment: @BackSlash lol thanks of course I messed up on that

Comment: @TungstenX Yeah, my bad. I should have specified the question for specific problem I was having more  clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test it but it should work. Don't hesitate to ask if you don't understand anything. I hope it's clean and nice enough.

**Multiplication Table Tester**

```
public class MultiplicationTableTester {

public static void main (String[] args) {
    int maxNum;
    System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    maxNum = in.nextInt();

    MultiplicationTable mT = new MultiplicationTable(maxNum);

    System.out.print(mT.createMultiplicationTable());
  }
}
```

**MultiplicationTable.java**

```
public class MultiplicationTable {
private int maxNum;

public MultiplicationTable(int maxNum) {
    this.maxNum = maxNum;
}

public String createMultiplicationTable() {
    StringBuilder table = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 1; i<=maxNum;i++){
       for(int j = 1; j<=10; j++){                            
          table.append(i*j);
          table.append("\t"); 
       }
       table.append("\n");
    }

    return table.toString();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked for what my teacher wanted the  output  to look like. Just had to change your j<=10, to j<maxNum. Not sure if it's a good program like that, but the output looks good.

Answer (score 0):

change  "/n" with "\n"

```
public String createMultiplacationTable() {
    String row = "";
    String col = "";
    String tmpRow= "";
    String tmpCol = "";
    String table = "";

while (i < maxNum) {
    tmpRow = "" + i;
    i++;
    row += tmpRow + "\t";

    tmpCol = "" + i;
    i++;
    col += tmpCol + "\n";
        for (int j = 1;  j < maxNum; j++) {
            System.out.print(" " + i * j);
}
        table = row + col;
}
return table;
```

}
}